# Angular 2 - .ts appends in all local files?

Tags: angular

I am developing an Angular 2 application and now I am facing an unexpected `.ts` file extension issue in all my local file includes.

See my code below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  template: require('./home.component.html')
})
```

Here I am getting error like

```
GET http://192.168.1.36/angular2/smd/app/home.component.html.ts 404 (Not Found)
```

How can I avoid the unwanted `.ts` extension from my local files?

Please suggest me a solution

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component annotation you only need to set the `templateUrl` to the path of your template file. Require is thought for loading other modules.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
```